# Get TChartSeries at XY Point in TChart

Tags: delphi, charts, delphi-7, teechart

I'm using the **TChart control that comes with Delphi 7** and wish to **get the Series and Value # of the line/bar under the mouse pointer.**

I'm aware of the OnClickSeries event which provides great info but **I really want this info when I *hover* over a series**.

EDIT: I found a hittest method on TChart which works with any series types and multiple series in the one chart so I've posted this and made it my accepted answer. Special Thanks to GameCat for his effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found this method which works with multiple series (even of different types) in a chart.

```
TChart.CalcClickedPart(Pos: TPoint; Var Part: TChartClickedPart);
```

The method fills a TChartClickedPart record which contains the following detailed hit-test information:

```
TChartClickedPart = record
  Part : TChartClickedPartStyle;
  PointIndex : Integer;
  ASeries : TChartSeries;
  AAxis : TChartAxis;
end;
```

This includes the Series and the ValueIndex (PointIndex) which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the OnChartMouseMove (or the OnSeriesMouseMove)

```
procedure TForm5.Chart1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  i := Series1.CalcClickedPie(x,y); // i = index of checked data -1 for none
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i));
end;
```

Ok, my bad, the code for bars is different (even easier):

```
procedure TForm5.Chart1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  i := Series1.GetCursorValueIndex;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I'm really after getting the series/value at a point in a Bar/Line chart.

Comment: It shouldn't be that different for other series.

Comment: Hehe, I totally agree they *shouldn't* be that different to other series - though I've been unable to find anything similar.

Comment: Added bar example, it is a mystery why those have to be different.

Comment: Dude, +1 for all the effort you put into this question. I eventually found a method which is exactly what I wanted so I've made it my answer but wish I could give you +10 for your help. Cheers heaps. :)